# Oracle PLSQL merge records within temporary table

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a procedure in PLSQL that fills up a temporary table. The data looks  like the following:

```
BUYER_NAME  QUANTITY   AMOUNT
-------------------------------
JOHN        10         1200
JOHN        12         1310
ALAN        15         1450
ALAN        10         1200
JOHN        20         2400
```

I need to sum up the quantities and amount for each buyer, then remove existing data and fill up the table again such that each buyer name comes only once with total quantity and amount.

I know this can be done if I create another temp table and transfer data through it. However, **is there a way we can merge the records within the same temporary table** (and within the same session)?

Comment: What about the `MERGE` statement? http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_9016.htm

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I wonder how a merge statement could work in this scenario because the source of data is the same table.

Comment: That's not a good way to operate. To do a good job I suggest you to populate a global temporary table with the procedure and then merge the grouped data into a final table where the BUYER_NAME is a unique column.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the problem here is with the initil pl/sql procedure that fills the table. Why not modify it to do this as well? I suspect that the answer would be that it makes much use of pl/sql -- if so, make every effort to convert it to SQL instead, or turn it into a pipelined function that you can select from and aggregate the output of.

That aside, I would just aggregate the result into a different table. I assume that these are global temporary tables, so there is really not much overhead in doing so as a direct path insert to a GTT would be much more efficient than modifying a table already in place.

Comment: I agree the aggregated sum and the "distinct" operation can most probably be done in a single query. And maybe that doesn't even need a temp table then (a pipelined function might be just enough).

Comment: Actually in the initial PLSQL the data cannot be aggregated. The data is processed (values calculated) and then inserted into temp table. Can I create two instances of same temp table within the same session and do the data transfer between them?

Comment: @asim-ishaq: I'm pretty sure you can aggregate the data within the same statemenent. Why don't you show us the statement that fills the temp table?

Comment: Look at using a pipelined function first -- if you don't need the detail results, don't write them. In answer to your question, temporary tables are best defined as "global temporary tables" as they are not subject to so much logging (specifically redo is not required as the data never needs to be recovered) and they are "self-emptying". You define them as a permanent part of your schema, not during processing. If you really needed two then create two separate ones.